# Hereditary class for $\operatorname{Free}(P3) \cup \operatorname{Free}(\text{co}-P_3)$

Tags: graph-theory

I have been trying to determine the hereditary class of the union of all cluster and complete multipartite graphs

$$\operatorname{Free}\left(P_3\right)\cup \operatorname{Free}\left(\text{co}-P_3\right)$$

in terms of minimal forbidden induced subgraphs.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

I am taking a Graph theory module, and this is one of the practice questions (it is not homework). I thought it might be $\operatorname{Free}\left(P_3,K_{1,3}\right)$ but got nothing sadly. I've been trying to think which subgraphs cannot be contained in either set. The module really just defined what a hereditary class is, minimal forbidden induced subgraphs, and cluster/complete multipartite graphs until this point. These are the definitions I have so far:

Cluster graphs are graphs formed from a disjoint union of cliques.

Complete Multipartite graphs are graphs which are a union of independent sets, containing all edges between any pair of independent sets.

Hereditary classes are sets which are closed to vertex deletions.